# 'Attempted relative import in non-package' although packages with __init__.py in one directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I have a module named `extended.py` which contains the following line:

```
from .basic import BasicModule
```

and the file `basic.py` resides in the same directory as does `__init__.py`. However, when I try to run it as:

```
python extended.py
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Also adding the line:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

does not solve the problem. 
Maybe I am too tired to see the obvious - but I don't see the problem here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attempted relative import in non-package even with \_\_init\_\_.py](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py)

Comment: how about `python -m parent_directory.extended`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do relative imports in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Relative imports only work for packages, but when you importing in `extended.py` you are running a *top-level module* instead.

The current directory may hold a `__init__.py` file but that doesn't make `exended.py` part of a package yet.

For something to be considered a package, you need to import the *directory name* instead. The following would work:

```
main.py

packagename\
    __init__.py
    basic.py
    extended.py
```

then in `main.py` put:

```
import packagename.extended
```

and only *then* is `extended` part of a package and do relative imports work.

The relative import now has something to be relative *to*, the `packagename` parent.

Comment: But how am I able to run `unittests` in that case? Do I hav to specify a python argument (-m) for these cases of imports?

Comment: For anything not defined in a package, don't use relative imports, use absolute imports instead. A unittest script is not part of the package, it is a external script.

Comment: I always thought one should put the unittests inside the same module? Is there a good-practices or a PEP on the unitest with python?

Comment: Sure, bundle the tests with the package, but perhaps not run the tests as scripts *directly*. Use another tool to discover tests instead, such as `nose`.

Comment: Ok that is fair enough. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you use setuptools, you can use that too; see [`test` - build a package and run a test suite](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite) for more info. The tests are then imported *from* the package and relative imports will work correctly.

Comment: I'm confused -- the OP never suggested importing extended.py -- he wants to import basic.py when extended.py is executed. Also, what is main.py? the OP never mentioned that file

Comment: @Paul: I've clarified the first sentence, that was indeed confusing.

Comment: @Paul: `main.py` is a new file my answer introduces, outside of the package.

Comment: got it. thanks! I was having the same problem and now its fixed.