# Python3 how do I import subdirectory file that imports subsubdirectory file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, package

So I'm trying to import a module from package that import its subpackage. Here is sample code:

```
main_directory
    - main.py
    subdirectory
        - __init__.py
        - test.py
        subsubdirectory
            - __init__.py
            - test2.py

main.py:
    from subdirectory import test
    test.foo1()

test.py:
    from subsubdirectory import test2
    def foo1():
        print("foo1")
        test2.foo2()

test2.py:
    def foo2():
        print("foo2")
```

in this case, if I change

```
from subsubdirectory import test2
```

to

```
from .subsubdirectory import test2
```

it works since I guess it's direct path?
But when I move to my subdirectory and run python3 test.py it will throw error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.subsubdirectory'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Can you explain what happened?

Comment: See [Attempted relative import in non-package' although packages with __init__.py in one directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664313/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-although-packages-with-init-py-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use relative import, you have to run script the package way.

Since there is no `__init__.py` in `main_directory`, the package is `subdirectory`

```
cd ./main_directory/
python -m subdirectory.test
python -m subdirectory.subsubdirectory.test2
```

If by any chance, you want the `main_directory` to be the package name, you have to add `__init__.py` inside `main_directory`, then, you run script:

```
cd ./main_directory/../
python -m main_directory.subdirectory.test
python -m main_directory.subdirectory.subsubdirectory.test2
```