# What's the right way to import another file from the same folder in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

The Python Zen says:

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it

What's the right way to import another file from the same folder in Python 2.7

```
.
└── myfolder
    ├── file1.py
    ├── file2.py
    └── __init__.py
```

(Assuming `__init__.py` is empty)

### Solution 1:

`file2.py` should contain

```
from myfolder import file1
```

this works fine: `python -m myfolder/file2`

However, this approach requires naming `myfolder` everywhere (which seems silly: you shouldn't have to refer to your family members by their last names and cities of origin)

### Solution 2:

On the other hand, this fails with "ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package":

```
from . import file1
```

### Solution 3:

as does this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from . import file1
```

### Solution 4:

And this version fails with "No module named file1":

```
import file1
```

### Solution 5:

Putting every file in its own folder with `__init__.py` next to it also doesn't seem like a very sane approach.

Comment: To what you think seems silly: explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `from .` is even more explicit, and doesn't need to be changed when packages get renamed, yet it doesn't work.

Comment: It works *within* a package. If you have dependencies *between* packages, they should be resolved by the name of the package rather than just where it happens to be. If that other package gets renamed, isn't it *right* that the reference also changes in other packages that use it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe myfolder is a package; file2 is in it; relative import doesn't work *within* myfolder. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Sorry, you're right; the problem is the way you're *running* it. It's because you're trying to run `file2.py` directly, rather than from outside `myfolder`. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/14664313/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nope: I'm running it as `python -m myfolder/file2`, outside myfolder (It's in the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things:

- `__init__.py` in `myfolder`
- in `file2.py`:

  ```
  from .file1 import *
  ```

  or

  ```
  from . import file1
  ```
- `python -m myfolder.file2`  (note the `.` and not the `/`)