# Import parent directory package without sys.path.append

Tags: python

I have a project structured as this:

```
parent/
   sub1/
      __init__.py
      directoryManager.py
   sub2
      tst.py
```

in tst.py, I am trying to import directoryManager as ld from sub1,
is there anyway to import it without using sys.path.append ?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
from .. import directoryManager
```

The extra `.` goes one dictionary up

If this is going to be a package installed to path  `from parent parent.sub1 import  directoryManager`

Comment: it gives me attempted relative import in non package error

Comment: @JialiangZhou  Does this post help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664313/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-although-packages-with-init-py-in

Comment: well，not really cause the tst.py are scheduled to run via a server using python not python -m, I was thinking if I can put the directoryManager to a root directory of the computer

Comment: @JialiangZhou  Unless I'm understanding the meaning of `root dictionary` incorrectly  `from parent.sub1 import  directoryManager` sould work

Comment: I add the package to python/site-packages but it works in Linux only . In windows, I put is at python27/Lib/site-packages but doesn't work

Comment: @JialiangZhou Hmm is site-packages added to the path variable?

Comment: I think so cause I saw other scrip import package located in site-packages

Comment: @JialiangZhou All I can suggest is create your setup.py file and install it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))

from sub1 import directoryManager
```

This should work.

Comment: Specifically says in the question without sys.path.append....

Answer (score 0):

### Recipe 1

```py
import importlib.machinery
import importlib.util
import sys
from pathlib import Path

finder = importlib.machinery.PathFinder()
spec = finder.find_spec(
    'directoryManager',
    [str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent / 'sub1')]
)
# or finder.find_spec('directoryManager', ['../sub1']) if cwd is sub2
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[name] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

This recipe doesn't need the full path of the file. Thus it is useful for importing extensions (they have suffixes like `.cpython-38-aarch64-linux-gnu.so`).

### Recipe 2

```py
import importlib.util
import sys
from pathlib import Path

spec = finder.spec_from_file_location(
    'directoryManager',
    str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent / 'sub1' / 'directoryManager.py')
)
# or finder.spec_from_file_location('directoryManager, '../sub1/directoryManager.py') if cwd is sub2
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[name] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

This recipe is more straightforward and simple.
Adapted from https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly

### Reference

https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#checking-if-a-module-can-be-imported
(`importlib.util.find_spec` internally use `PathFinder.find_spec`)